# How not to enable button when changing values in DecimalUpDown in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two DecimalUpDown.

One of maximum and one of minimum.

The button should not be enabled if the minimum is greater than the maximum.

**XAML**

```
<tool:DecimalUpDown  Name="min"  Value="0.00" />
<tool:DecimalUpDown  Name="Max"  Value="0.00" />
<Button x:Name="Aplly" IsEnabled="{Binding MaxSmallerMin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Aplly" >
```

**C#**

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = this;
  }
 public bool MaxSmallerMin
        {
            get {
                if (min.Text != "" && max.Text != "")
                    if (Convert.ToDouble(min.Text) <= Convert.ToDouble(max.Text))
                        return true;
                return false;
            }            
        }
```

But that doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the GUI that your `MaxSmallerMin` property has changed. You can use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to do so. When `min.Text` or `max.Text` changes, you'll have to invoke the corresponding event. Your code might look like this:

C#:

```
class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public MainWindow()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = this;
  }

 public bool MaxSmallerMin
        {
            get {
                if (min.Text != "" && max.Text != "")
                    if (Convert.ToDouble(min.Text) <= Convert.ToDouble(max.Text))
                        return true;
                return false;
            }            
        }

private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
   {
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MaxSmallerMin)));
   }
}
```

XAML:

```
<tool:DecimalUpDown  Name="min" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler" Value="0.00" />
<tool:DecimalUpDown  Name="Max" TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler" Value="0.00" />
```

Comment: It doesn't know PropertyChangedEvents

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I already fixed it. See also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1)